# How to select all records for only the first 50 distinct values in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a classifier model for a dataset, but I have too many distinct values for my target variable.  If I run something like this:

```
Create or replace model `model_name`
options (model_type="AUTOML_CLASSIFIER", input_label_cols=["ORIGIN_AIRPORT"]) as
select DAY_OF_WEEK, ARRIVAL_TIME, ARRIVAL_DELAY, ORIGIN_AIRPORT
from `table_name`
limit 1000
```

I end up getting

> **Error running query**
> Classification model currently only supports classification with up to 50 unique labels and the label column had 111 unique labels.

So how can I select, for example, all rows that have one of the first 50 values of `ORIGIN_AIRPORT`?

Comment: First 50 values or first 50 unique values? And how do you define 'first'? Order by `ARRIVAL_TIME` descending? If so, it could be Latest 50 values so it could be `ORDER BY ARRIVAL_TIME DESC LIMIT 50`.

Comment: I don't care which order.  It could be 50 unique, random values, for all I care.  But I don't want just those 50 records, I want all records with those 50 unique origin_airports.

Comment: Then maybe you can extract the 50 unique values first, make it as a subquery then do a join from the table again to get all the data according to the 50 unique that you've obtained.

Comment: Ooh, great idea, thanks!

Comment: Once you've managed to construct the working query for your situation, please post them as (your own) answer and accept it; so it can be useful for others who are looking for the same solution in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I ended up having a lot of trouble getting that method to work, so I just separately created a new table with the first 50 values and then joined the two tables.

Comment: Can you post the method you've tried into your question? And (if any) errors or issues you're facing with it? Maybe we can work something out.

Comment: @PeterOhaver Is your problem solved on this question?

Comment: I resolved the issue by just creating a new table. I may be able to check later today, but I've moved on from the project I was working on.

Comment: Okay yeah you can create a new table too. Check my answer I have implemented the same with a left join in the outer query with a inner subquery fetching me the 50 unique values. You can try the solution and let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given a table of values (origin_airport), with unique identifiers (id) and date, find the minimum date for each unique value (origin_airport) to decide which N origin_airport values are to be returned.

Return all rows which match the first 3 unique origin_airport values (densely ranked, by min(date) per origin_airport).

Updated: to use columns that more closely match the model, with origin_airport and a date column for ordering.

[Full working test case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ab3cb6902d434e3261bbff9687f7504f)

The test data:

```
CREATE TABLE airportlogs (
   origin_airport   int
 , id    int primary key auto_increment
 , date  date DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO airportlogs (origin_airport) VALUES
    (  1 )
  , (  1 )
  , (  8 )
  , (  8 )
  , (  8 )
  , (  7 )
  , (  7 )
  , (  6 )
  , (  5 )
  , (  4 )
  , (  3 )
  , (  3 )
  , (  7 )
  , (  7 )
  , (  1 )
  , (  8 )
  , (  3 )
  , (  1 )
;

-- Create some dates to use for ordering.
-- Ordering can be as complicated as we need.
UPDATE airportlogs SET date = current_date + INTERVAL +id DAY;

-- Intermediate calculation to show the MIN(date) per origin_airport

WITH nvals (origin_airport, mdate) AS (
        SELECT origin_airport, MIN(date) AS mdate FROM airportlogs GROUP BY origin_airport
     )
SELECT *
  FROM nvals
 ORDER BY mdate
;

+----------------+------------+
| origin_airport | mdate      |
+----------------+------------+
|              1 | 2021-08-05 |
|              8 | 2021-08-07 |
|              7 | 2021-08-10 |
|              6 | 2021-08-12 |
|              5 | 2021-08-13 |
|              4 | 2021-08-14 |
|              3 | 2021-08-15 |
+----------------+------------+

-- Calculation of ordered rank for the unique origin_airport values
-- by MIN(date) per origin_airport.

WITH nvals0 (origin_airport, date, mdate) AS (
        SELECT origin_airport
             , date
             , MIN(date) OVER (PARTITION BY origin_airport) AS mdate
          FROM airportlogs
     )
   , nvals (origin_airport, date, mdate, r) AS (
        SELECT origin_airport
             , date
             , mdate
             , DENSE_RANK()  OVER (ORDER BY mdate)      AS r
          FROM nvals0
     )
SELECT *
  FROM nvals
 ORDER BY r, date
;

Result:
+----------------+------------+------------+---+
| origin_airport | date       | mdate      | r |
+----------------+------------+------------+---+
|              1 | 2021-08-05 | 2021-08-05 | 1 |
|              1 | 2021-08-06 | 2021-08-05 | 1 |
|              1 | 2021-08-19 | 2021-08-05 | 1 |
|              1 | 2021-08-22 | 2021-08-05 | 1 |
|              8 | 2021-08-07 | 2021-08-07 | 2 |
|              8 | 2021-08-08 | 2021-08-07 | 2 |
|              8 | 2021-08-09 | 2021-08-07 | 2 |
|              8 | 2021-08-20 | 2021-08-07 | 2 |
|              7 | 2021-08-10 | 2021-08-10 | 3 |
|              7 | 2021-08-11 | 2021-08-10 | 3 |
|              7 | 2021-08-17 | 2021-08-10 | 3 |
|              7 | 2021-08-18 | 2021-08-10 | 3 |
|              6 | 2021-08-12 | 2021-08-12 | 4 |
|              5 | 2021-08-13 | 2021-08-13 | 5 |
|              4 | 2021-08-14 | 2021-08-14 | 6 |
|              3 | 2021-08-15 | 2021-08-15 | 7 |
|              3 | 2021-08-16 | 2021-08-15 | 7 |
|              3 | 2021-08-21 | 2021-08-15 | 7 |
+----------------+------------+------------+---+
```

The final solution:

```
WITH min_date (origin_airport, date, mdate) AS (
        SELECT origin_airport
             , date
             , MIN(date) OVER (PARTITION BY origin_airport) AS mdate   
          FROM airportlogs
     )
   , ranks (origin_airport, date, mdate, r) AS (
        SELECT origin_airport
             , date
             , mdate
             , DENSE_RANK()  OVER (ORDER BY mdate)      AS r   
          FROM min_date
     )
SELECT *
  FROM ranks
 WHERE r <= 3    
 ORDER BY r, date
;

The final result:
+----------------+------------+------------+---+
| origin_airport | date       | mdate      | r |
+----------------+------------+------------+---+
|              1 | 2021-08-05 | 2021-08-05 | 1 |
|              1 | 2021-08-06 | 2021-08-05 | 1 |
|              1 | 2021-08-19 | 2021-08-05 | 1 |
|              1 | 2021-08-22 | 2021-08-05 | 1 |
|              8 | 2021-08-07 | 2021-08-07 | 2 |
|              8 | 2021-08-08 | 2021-08-07 | 2 |
|              8 | 2021-08-09 | 2021-08-07 | 2 |
|              8 | 2021-08-20 | 2021-08-07 | 2 |
|              7 | 2021-08-10 | 2021-08-10 | 3 |
|              7 | 2021-08-11 | 2021-08-10 | 3 |
|              7 | 2021-08-17 | 2021-08-10 | 3 |
|              7 | 2021-08-18 | 2021-08-10 | 3 |
+----------------+------------+------------+---+
```

There are a number of other solutions.

The poster didn't mention the logic for this ordering.  But with the above window function behavior, that's trivial to specify.

Comment: @PeterOhaver Here's a full test case with columns more in line with your model, just as an example.  This finds only the first 3 unique origin_airport values and returns all rows associated with them.  I believe that was the rough request.  It's directly based on the above solution, which I'll update: `https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=96f039cf9fc19a8fb9e426609a5595d6`

Comment: Link to test case is updated in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Select * from “TABLE_NAME” as T1 left outer join (SELECT distinct
> COLUMN_NAME from TABLE_NAME Order by  COLUMN_NAME limit 50)as T2 on
> T1.COLUMN_NAME=T2.COLUMN_NAME

This query will fetch you  50 distinct values in the inner query, then the outer query searches for those  particular 50 distinct values using the T1.COLUMN_NAME=T2.COLUMN_NAME commands and returns all the records( it shows null for those not included in the 50 unique list)